# Should we set LiveData and/or kotlin Flows to null in ViewModel onCleared?

Tags: android, android-livedata, android-viewmodel, kotlin-stateflow

I figured that since both LiveData & Flow should be lifecycle aware that there is no reason to do this.  Is there any benefit or detriment to setting them to null yourself in onCleared?

Comment: This depends on a your use case, you need to share your code to get a precise answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since both LiveData and Flow are lifecycle-aware they will automatically clean up their resources in the ViewModel's `onCleared()` method. So there's no need to explicitly set them to `null`.

Comment: would there ever be a reason to create the livedata in a fragment/activity?  When is a flow preferable to LiveData?